# Application icon size in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xcasset

What should be the application icon resolution in Xcode ?

I couldn't find the sizes for 2x and 3x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iPhone, the standard resolution of app icon is `60*60px`. And the corresponding 2x and 3x versions of it are `120*120px` and `180*180px` respectively.

For iPad, the standard resolution of app icon is `76*76px`. And the 2x version is `152*152px`. There is no 3x app icon on iPad.

Comment: Thanks for that info - I was wondering what 3x and 2x mean - now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the app icon template which creates all of the versions for you. You can see it on [this](https://appicontemplate.com) link. It is the easiest way to generate those.

`@3x` or `@2x` can be upscaled from `@1x`
But to answer your question what are those.

Normal device - `1 pixel = 1 point@1x` (Older iPhone and iPad devices)

Retina device - `4 pixels(2 x 2) = 1 point@2x` (iPhone 5+)

Retina iPhone6 and iPad - `9 pixels (3 x 3) = 1 point@3x` (iPhone6+)

iPhone app icon standard resolution is `60*60px`.

iPad app icon standard resolution is `76*76px`.

You need all 3 of those versions because there are three kind of apple devices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the needed size :

- Clicked on the image in Assets
- The size is written on the right of the Xcode, `at the property inspector`.